# SQL help different value on the same field

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with a request.
I've two tables : `ADDRESS` and `CUSTOM`
I can link the two tables with `ADDRESS.ID = CUSTOM.ADDRESSID`
And I want to select all the addresses where `CUSTOM.NAME = 'NUMBER'`
and `CUSTOM.VALUE = '5'`
But also, on these addresses, I want to display the field `CUSTOM.VALUE`, where `CUSTOM.NAME = 'INFO'`

Here is some exemples

ADDRESS :

```
 ID      NAME      STREET
 1       Paul     65 blue street
 2       John     50 red street
```

CUSTOM :

```
ID      IDADDRESS     NAME    VALUE
 1           1         NUMBER    5
 2           1         INFO      1st floor
 3           2         NUMBER    6
 4           2         INFO      no info
```

What I want in result is :
Paul - 65 blue street - 1st floor

Can someone help me with this request please ? 
I tried :

`SELECT * FROM ADDRESS, CUSTOM WHERE ADDRESS.ID=CUSTOM.ADDRESSID AND         ((CUSTOM.NAME='NUMBER' AND CUSTOM.VALUE='5') OR CUSTOM.NAME='INFO')`

Comment: Don't store data like that, with different rows for different type of data, it will only cause you problems. (Maybe you've already noticed...)

Comment: I know, unfortunatly, the database I'm working on isn't mine, and I have no choice about it.

Comment: You need to join CUSTOM one more time.

Comment: can you explain how please ? I tried to search about JOIN, or UNION, but I managed to run none of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, joining CUSTOM twice

```
SELECT *
FROM ADDRESS, CUSTOM c1, CUSTOM c2
WHERE ADDRESS.ID = c1.ADDRESSID
 AND  c1.ADDRESSID = c2.ADDRESSID and c1.NAME <> c2.NAME
```

Maybe I removed some conditions still needed...

Comment: @NeS - `as` isn't valid for table aliases in Oracle, so just remove both appearances of that keyword.

Comment: Thanks for editing. (Didn't know about that Oracle syntax special.)

Answer (score 0):

The table 'CUSTOM' appears to hold 2 different types of data, NUMBER and INFO. This means you should essentially treat both types of data as different tables, and join each seperately. Your query would/could like this:

```
SELECT a.NAME 
,   a.STREET 
,   inf.VALUE
FROM ADDRESS a
JOIN CUSTOM num
ON a.ID      = num.IDADDRESS
AND num.NAME = 'NUMBER'
JOIN CUSTOM inf
ON a.ID         = inf.IDADDRESS
AND inf.NAME    = 'INFO'
WHERE num.VALUE = '5'
```

If you have the option, try making the table CUSTOM into 2 actual tables, each only containing a single type of data. This will make it clear to other developers what type of data is in the table, and how to use the tables correctly.

Comment: Or just create `INFO` and `NUMBER` as *columns* in the `CUSTOM` table

Comment: That would work too. Using columns is probably better if these are the only two fields, and you will mostly retrieve/use the two together.

Answer (score 0):

I would to the following (it doesn't appear you actually need the value of the "custom NUMBER" field):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.street, c.value
  FROM address a LEFT JOIN custom c
    ON a.id = c.addressid
   AND c.name = 'INFO'
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM custom c1
                 WHERE c1.addressid = a.id
                   AND c1.name = 'NUMBER'
                   AND c1.value = '5' );
```

This will get all the rows in `ADDRESS` for which a corresponding row in `CUSTOM` exists where `name` = `'NUMBER'` and `value` = `'5'`. It will also retrieve these rows even if there isn't a corresponding `'INFO'` row (hence the `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`) ... in these cases a `NULL` will be returned for the custom value.